# Regarding performance optimization techniques to be keep while coding

Tags: java

As I was doing a research on  measure elapsed execution time in Java by using System.currentTimeinMillis() on a piece if a code that is shown below but my Query is what other performance techniques we should keep in mind while codeing besides measuring the time , My query is focussed more on performance optimaztion techniques..

```
    public class MeasureTimeExampleJava {



    public static void main(String args[]) {

        //measuring elapsed time using System.nanoTime
        long startTime = System.nanoTime();
        for(int i=0; i< 1000000; i++){
            Object obj = new Object();
        }
        long elapsedTime = System.nanoTime() - startTime;

        System.out.println("Total execution time to create 1000K objects in Java in millis: "
                + elapsedTime/1000000);

        //measuring elapsed time using Spring StopWatch
        StopWatch watch = new StopWatch();
        watch.start();
        for(int i=0; i< 1000000; i++){
            Object obj = new Object();
        }
        watch.stop();
        System.out.println("Total execution time to create 1000K objects in Java using StopWatch in millis: "
                + watch.getTotalTimeMillis());
    }   

}

Output:
Total execution time to create 1000K objects in Java in millis: 18
Total execution time to create 1000K objects in Java using StopWatch in millis: 15
```

Comment: Did you have a question?

Comment: @HotLicks.. what other performance techniques we should keep in mind while codeing besides measuring the time..?

Comment: (I'm relatively certain that this thread is a duplicate of about 50 others, but I'm too lazy to look up its predecessors.)

Answer (score 1):

Here are the steps I take when attempting to keep optimization of the code in mind:

- Use best practices for architecture / design
- Write easy-to-maintain code
- Measure the result with a profiler
- Go and optimize only parts of the code that the profiler say need attention
- Only spend time optimizing things that will affect the actual user of the program

My profiler will show me various areas of interest

- CPU hotspots
- Excessive memory use (can manifest in heavy GC and/or heavy swapping)
- Excessive IO (disk, network)

Answer (score 0):

I'd say that you should care about lots of other things, all of which should be accessible via a tool like Visual VM:

1. CPU
2. All generations of heap
3. Threads running and their states
4. Objects being created and disposed of
5. Garbage collection cycles
6. Network traffic
7. Resource allocation and cleanup

Micro tests like this are rarely helpful.  The JVM uses runtime statistics to optimize performance, so "burn in" can be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

The number one rule of optimization is DON'T.  Unless you know very precisely what you're doing, you'll optimize the wrong things, miss the right things, make performance worse, and destroy reliability and readability.

Concentrate on writing well-structured, well-documented, compact code.  If optimization is needed later it will be much easier to accomplish.

(And be aware that measuring the performance of `new Object()` in Java is a fools errand.  The garbage collector is the 800 pound gorilla in the room, so all your measurements will be useless.)

Answer (score 0):

You are testing two different ways of measuring elapsed time. Your test is flawed as you're running both tests in the same JVM execution. This runs the risk of the first test warming up caches and impact the second test. The correct way is to run each test in its own JVM execution.